# Append to a filename last modified date and time with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename, datemodified

I am trying to copy all `*.csv` files from a folder to another folder, but while copying I need to add modified date and time of file to filename. For example, if filename is `Test.csv` and it was modified on `11/21/2018` `15:01:10` output should be `Test11-21-201815_01-10.csv`. I found a script to add current timestamp to it, but I need to add modified date of file. You can see it below:

```
@echo off
set Source=C:\csvtest
set Target=C:\csvtest\csvtest\Archive
FOR /f "tokens=1-8 delims=/.:- " %%A in ("%date%%time%") DO (
SET Month=%%B
SET Day=%%C
SET Year=%%D
SET Hours=%%E
SET Minutes=%%F
SET Seconds=%%G
SET All=%%B-%%C-%%D_%%E-%%F-%%G
)

FOR %%i IN ("%Source%\*.csv") DO (
COPY "%%i" "%Target%\%%~Ni %All%.csv")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples here on SO for appending a date,
but I'd use PowerShell as a tool to accomplish this (wrapped in batch).

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\23\SO_53450598.cmd
@echo off
set "Source=C:\test"
set "Target=C:\test\Archive"
PowerShell -Nop -C "Get-ChildItem '%Source%\*.csv'|Copy-Item -Destination {'%Target%\{0} {1:MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss}.csv' -f $_.BaseName,$_.LastWriteTime} -WhatIf"
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly faster way in batch file that uses `delayedexpansion`:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%a IN ('forfiles /M file.ext /C "cmd /C echo @fdate @ftime"') do (
 set line1=%%a
 set line2=%%b
 set line1r=!line1:/=-!
 set line2r=!line2::=-!
 rename "file.ext" "file!line1r!!line2r!.ext"
)
rem NOTE: Date format is DD-MM-YYYY. Time format is HH-MM-SS.
```

- `forfiles /M file.ext /C "cmd /C echo @fdate @ftime"` runs the command (`/C`) for the file specified in `/M` option (`file.ext`).
- `"cmd /C echo @fdate @ftime"` opens a new cmd and carry out the command specified by string and then terminates it.
- `@fdate` is the last modified date of the file and `@ftime` is the last modified time of the file.

We set variables `line1` and `line2` for each of `@fdate` and `@ftime` and then we make some format changes to them.

Finally, we rename `file.ext` to `fileDD-MM-YYYYHH-MM-SS.ext`.

Comment: With copy operations involved I don't think my batch is remarkably slower, if at all. And OP wants to copy - not rename.